# how to create a temporary table using master-slave concept

Tags: asp.net

I am newbie in asp.net technology. Recently I have been creating a form in asp.net. This form contains a gridview, which has columns names `employee name`, `salary`, `location`. These are extracted from the DB (master) having `employee_id` as primary key. When I click the update button in gridview, the control goes back to add employee.

**PROBLEM:**: I want to automatically update another table (slave), which has `formula_id` as primary key, `salary`, `location`, `relatedheadid` and this table should be temporary. i:e 1st master should execute and than the field values in mater table are to be updated in slave table.

Comment: If you ask for code in a question, you should add solutions you have tried, and tell why they didn't work. Please edit this question via the edit link under your question and add this code.

Comment: you can create stored procedure to update the values of first table.Then get the inserted values from the master table using variables and update it in your slave table.